# Modulo, help solving

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$, $a$ and $b$ are positive integers and $a | b$, $a$ divides $b$, $b \mod a = 0$ we have:

$$
(x \mod b) \mod a = x \mod a \quad\quad\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

Prove:

$$
x \equiv y \quad(\mod b) \quad\text{ implies}\quad x \equiv \quad(\mod a) \\
\forall x, y \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

I am not looking for a straight answer, but how to go about solving this.

I have manipulated these equations in many ways trying to get an answer, but I just cannot seem to wrap my head around it.

Here are some things I have tried:

$$
\begin{aligned}
x \equiv y \quad(\mod b) &\quad\quad x \equiv y \quad(\mod a) \\
x \mod b = x \mod y &\quad\quad x \mod a = y \mod a
\end{aligned} \\ \\
(x \mod b) \mod a = y \mod a \\
(y \mod b) \mod a = y \mod a
$$

This basically manipulates what I want to prove, but all it does is swap $x$ for $y$, which does not seem right.

$$
x \equiv y \quad(\mod b) \\
x = y + kb \\
x \equiv y \quad(\mod a) \\
x = y + ka \\
y + kb = y +ka
$$

This of course does not work as $a \not= b$ and is just forced.

I am not sure how to reconcile this.

Comment: When you say $x\equiv y\pmod{b}$ this does indeed mean that there is some integer $k_1$ such that $x=y+k_1b$.  Similarly, when you say $x\equiv y\pmod{a}$ this means that there is some integer $k_2$ such that $x=y+k_2a$.  *These don't need to be the same!*  There is no reason to expect $k_1$ to equal $k_2$.  As such, you should avoid using the same name for each as you did above.  You called them both "$k$" and confused yourself.

Comment: That being said, we want to show that $x\equiv y\pmod{b}$ implies $x\equiv y\pmod{a}$... we do not assume that both are true, we only assume the first is true and *show* that the second must follow.  So, we have $x=y+kb$ and since $a\mid b$ there must be some $l$ such that... (*use what it means for $a$ to divide $b$*)... and by rearranging we get... which implies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prelim: If $m|n$ and $n|k$ then $m|k$.

Pf:  $m|n \implies \frac nm \in \mathbb Z$.  And $n|k \implies \frac kn \in \mathbb Z$.   So  $\frac km =\frac nm * \frac kn\in \mathbb Z$.  So $m|k$.

....

So $x \equiv y \mod b \iff b|(x - y)$.

And we have $a|b$.

So $a|(x-y)$.

But $a|(x-y) \iff x \equiv y \mod b$.

That's it.

........

Note: if you use *any* definiton of $m|n$ ($n = km$ for some integer $m$ or $n \equiv 0 \mod m$)

And if you use any definition of $x \equiv y \mod b$ ($x = y + kb$ for some integer $m$; of $\frac xb$ and $\frac yb$ have the same remainder; or $b|x-y$) the prove would still be the same)

Example:

Prelim: $m|n$ means $n = jm$ for some integer $j$ and $n|k$ means $k = ln$ for some integer $l$.  So $k = (lj)m$ so $m|k$.

$x \equiv y \mod b$ means $x = y + jb$ for some integer $j$.  But we have $a|b$ so $b = la$ for some integer $l$.  So $x = y + (jl)a$ so $x \equiv y \mod a$.

Answer (score 1):

You're making more complex than they are: $x\equiv y\mod b$ means $x-y$ is divisible b, i.e. there exists $k\in \mathbf Z$ such that $x-y=kb$.

Now, if $a\mid b$, we can write $b=ca$ for some integer $c$, so
$$x-y=kb=k(ca)=(kc)a,$$
which means $x\equiv y\mod a$.